# ¿Qué tan común era la expresión "dar plomo" en la Colombia de los años 90?

Tags: expresiones, colombia

La serie de televisión [Narcos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcos) narra la vida del narcotraficante colombiano Pablo Escobar hasta su muerte en 1993.

En un artículo que hace referencia al libro [*Pablo Escobar: el patrón del mal*](http://www.cambio21.cl/cambio21/site/artic/20130312/pags/20130312113535.html) recopilan algunas de las expresiones y me gustó recordar esta:

> *Dar plomo*: cuando Pablo Escobar se enoja y se quiere deshacer de alguien le da un balazo. Es decir, le da plomo.

Al fin y al cabo, la expresión **plata o plomo** se ha convertido en la fetiche de todo aquel que habla de la serie.

Sin embargo, el hecho de que [Bogotalogo](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital) no recoja el término, que [el actor se caracterizara por hablar un español bastante malo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62015/4078) (es brasileño) y tener en cuenta las típicas licencias estilísticas que las series crean para darles más espectacularidad, me hace dudar de cuán común era la expresión.

Estuve unos meses viviendo en Colombia y no recuerdo haber oído nunca esta expresión (por otra parte, tampoco frecuenté narcotraficantes ni asesinos) y la descubrí viendo la serie.

Por tanto: ¿qué tan común era la expresión en la Colombia, especialmente Medellín, de principio de los años 90? ¿se usa aún? ¿y en otros países?

Comment: Pues al menos aquí en México si se usa, común en el centro y norte del país (al menos) incluso por niños, y se puede encontrar en la letra de algunos [Narcocorridos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcocorrido)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión **dar plomo** fue y sigue siendo muy utilizada para todo lo relacionado con armas de fuego.

No sé desde cuándo se utiliza pero la he escuchado desde siempre y actualmente reemplaza en el lenguaje coloquial a "disparar" en casi cualquier conversación que tenga que ver con armas de fuego sin necesidad de que tenga nada que ver con narcos.

Por ejemplo al hablar sobre un robo a un banco en el que intervenga la policía el narrador podría decir:

> ...y cuando llegó la policía se armó una **plomacera**<sup>(1)</sup> la berraca<sup>(2)</sup> y a uno de los ladrones le alcanzaron a **dar plomo**<sup>(3)</sup> y quedó *listo*<sup>(4)</sup>.

<sup>(1) plomacera: intercambio de disparos de arma de fuego.</sup>
 <sup>(2) la berraca: impresionante, extraordinaria [(*)](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=berraco) ([**](http://www.semana.com/opinion/articulo/verraco-berraco/10346-3)) ([***](http://www.destinocafe.com/es/ieventos/ver/621/el-berraco-de-guacas/))</sup> 
 <sup>(3) dar plomo: disparar</sup>
 <sup>(4) *listo*: muerto</sup>

Comment: Esta pregunta iba dirigida a ti, DGaleano, qué bien que cogieras el guante :) ¿Podrías indicar la traducción de _berraca_ también? Supongo que a muchos les sonará nueva la palabra.

Comment: @fedorqui ahí dejo también la definición puntual de _berraco_ y algunas referencias a sus otros usos y su "origen"

Answer (score 1):

La expresión dar plomo era y es bastante común en varios países de habla hispana. Su origen es producto de que las primeras armas de mano contenían proyectiles de este material Plomo Pb.

> Disparale una bala de plomo 
>   
> Disparale un plomo
>   
> Dale plomo

De acá proviene su uso. Y en la actualidad en los ambientes informales sigue siendo muy usada.

Comment: Gracias Daniel por indicar el origen de la expresión.